# How to I get the correct document root when tunneling my php project using ngrok and MAMP Pro?

Tags: php, mamp-pro, ngrok

I am trying to use ngrok to tunnel my project. It's named frontend and points to port 8888 and has a specific document root (not the default /Applications/MAMP/htdocs) When I start up my server I have no problem seeing it locally. But when I try to create a tunnel passing the command

./ngrok http frontend:8888

the url it gives me just takes me to the basic MAMP pro success page and not my website. The basic MAMP Pro site says my document root is /Applications/MAMP/htdocs so I think this might be related to the problem but I'm really not sure. I've successfully used ngrok before but not with my php project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was able to get it working using -host-header=rewrite

example: ngrok http -host-header=rewrite localhost:8888